# Server-Client Windows Form Application C#

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server

I'm trying to set up a server and client simulation in visual studio but having issues in getting it to work. Both programs run but that's all I get as output is "System.Byte[]". This is my first time in trying to make an application such as this. I worked off some code from a console application so I've been trying to adapt it to suit a windows form.

Here's the client code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Client has Made Connection to Server OK";

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        int port;
        port = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
        IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBox5.Text), port);


        sck.Connect(endpoint);

        //textBox1.Text = "Client has Made Connection to Server OK";

        Byte[] recbuffer = new byte[255];
        int rec = sck.Receive(recbuffer, 0, recbuffer.Length, 0);
        Array.Resize(ref recbuffer, rec);

        string temp = recbuffer.ToString();

        textBox2.Text = "Received: {0}" + temp;

        // sending string to server
        string msg = textBox3.Text;
        byte[] msgbuffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(msg);
        sck.Send(msgbuffer, 0, msgbuffer.Length, 0);


        Console.Read();
    }
```

And here's the server code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9939);
        Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        sck.Bind(ip);
        sck.Listen(0);

        Socket acc = sck.Accept();

        textBox1.Text = "Connection has been made to the server from the Client";

        byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello sent from Server to Client");
        string displayBuffer = buffer.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = displayBuffer;
        acc.Send(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);

        byte[] recbuffer = new byte[255];

        int rec = acc.Receive(recbuffer, 0, recbuffer.Length, 0);

        Array.Resize(ref recbuffer, rec);

        string temp = recbuffer.ToString();

        textBox3.Text = "received from client the string: " + temp;

        Console.Read();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the line

```
 string temp = recbuffer.ToString();
```

both on client code and on server code.

You need to change to

```
 string temp = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(recbuffer);
```

Asking a byte array to return a string through the ToString method returns just the name of the class because a byte array is not capable to convert itself in a string.